# zip:create seems not to work in Erlang 22, on windows

Tags: erlang, zip, elixir

I have been using `:zip.create/3` without issues for quite some time.

After updating to Elixir 1.9.2 on Erlang 22, I now get this error:  `{:error, :einval}`

Any help please?

```
defmodule Utils do
   def zip_test do
    data = {"demo.txt", File.read!("demo.txt")}
    IO.puts(inspect(data, @format))
    :zip.create("demo.zip", [data], [:memory])
  end
end
```

```
iex> Utils.zip_test
{"demo.txt", "this is a demo"}
{:error, :einval}
iex>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types of the arguments required for the erlang function [:zip.create()](https://erldocs.com/21.0/stdlib/zip.html?i=12&search=zip#create/3) are erlang string types.  In erlang, a string type is a list of integers.  In erlang, as a shortcut, you can create a list of integers with double quotes, e.g. "hello". The list will contain the ASCII codes for the specified characters.  On the other hand, in elixir double quotes create an *elixir string*, which is equivalent to an *erlang binary* type.  Therefore, you are providing binary arguments when you need to be providing lists of integers.

You can use the elixir function [String.to_charlist()](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_charlist/1) to create a list of integers from an elixir string:

```
:zip.create(String.to_charlist("demo.zip"),
           [String.to_charlist("demo.txt")],
           [:memory])
```

Or, you can just use single quotes in elixir to create a list of integers:

```
:zip.create('demo.zip', 
            ['demo.txt'], 
            [:memory])
```

For more info, see [Erlang Interoperability](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/advanced/erlang/#strings).

Comment: I must have mangled my code some how, i had used this :zip:create a while back. Thanks